# Conda: remove root environment and uninstall it

Tags: conda

How can I remove the root enviroment in conda in my Ubuntu 16.04 system?
I would like remove also conda.
I tried with:

```
$ conda env remove -n root

CondaEnvironmentError: Environment error: cannot remove current environment. deactivate and run conda remove again
```

then I tried to remove conda using pip, but I receive the following warning:

```
$ sudo -H pip uninstall conda

DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (conda) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
Uninstalling conda-4.3.13:
  /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda-4.3.13-py2.7.egg-info
Proceed (y/n)? n
```

Is it possible to remove completely conda from an ubuntu system?

Comment: Yes, simply delete the installation directory and remove the entry from your  PATH environment variable

Comment: The problem is that I have not the entry from my PATH env.
I installed conda via pip and the executable is:
`$ which conda
/usr/local/bin/conda`

How can I find the installation directory?

Comment: Then why not `pip uninstall conda`?

Comment: With `pip uninstall conda` I uninstall only conda, but not the root enviroment created previously by conda. In particular conda replaced the ubuntu 16.04 default python 2.7.12 with python 2.7.13. We solved uninstalling conda and removing manually the pyhon 2.7.13.